# Laravel multi file validation fails

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I have a multiple file input field:

`<input type="file" id="documents" name="documents[]" multiple>`

In my ProjectRequest class, I have the following rules applied:

```
$documents = count($this->input('documents'));
foreach(range(0, $documents) as $index) {
    $rules['documents.' . $index] = 'mimes:doc,pdf,jpeg,bmp,png|max:20000';
}
```

But when I try to upload a png or pdf I get the following validation error:

> The documents.0 must be a file of type: doc, pdf, jpeg, bmp, png.

## Update:

As suggested in the answers, instead of looping through the array, I directly added the `documents.*` rule in the `$rules` array. However I still get the same error.

In ProjecRequest:

---

```
$rules = [
  'documents.*' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,jpeg,bmp,png|max:20000',
];
return $rules;
```

In ProjectController@store:

---

```
public function store(ProjectRequest $request)
{
   $project = Project::create([
     /*key=>value removed to keep the question clean*/
   ]);

   foreach ($request->documents as $document) {
       $filename = $document->store('documents');
       Document::create([
          'project_id' => $project->id,
          'filepath' => $filename
       ]);
   }
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `loop` through the array, rather use `*`.

```
$rules['documents.*'] = 'mimes:doc,pdf,jpeg,bmp,png|max:20000';
```

Read Laravel Official [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays) for better understanding.

Comment: I removed the loop. Added this new rule to $rules[] array and I am still getting the same error

Comment: check your file type that you uploaded and show us your full validation code

Comment: checked, it was png.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: did you enable `multipart formdata` in your form in blade file?? Could you show us full form from blade/view file.

Comment: I did. `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I can't. Are you sure using only `documents.*` is the appropriate rule? Because nowhere in the documentation I see that rule. The documentation suggests this format `documents.*.filename`

Comment: validation is okay, that's why you are having the message, may be you should update your question with complete form code and you code try to echo `$document->getClientOriginalExtension()` to see what your input extension is in your controller removing validation class parameter.

Comment: Found the source of the problem. I like to keep my forms separate. So I often define my `forms` in a different blade layout. This is my common structure: `<form> @include('layouts.forms.contact')</form>`. This approach has led me to run into this error. I added enctype attribute to the wrong form because they both share the same include. Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate arrays with:

```
'documents.*' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,jpeg,bmp,png|max:20000'
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: I removed the loop. Added this new rule to $rules[] array and I am still getting the same error

Comment: @Eisenheim that is not error. It's the validation works as expected. It means the file you're trying to upload has the wrong mime type.

Comment: Tested with multiple files. All of them can't have wrong mime type @alexey-mezenin

Comment: @Eisenheim well, looks like they have.

Comment: Are you sure using only `documents.*` is the appropriate rule? Because nowhere in the documentation I see that rule. The documentation suggests this format `documents.*.filename`

Comment: Found the source of the problem. I like to keep my forms separate. So I often define my `forms` in a different blade layout. This is my common structure: `<form> @include('layouts.forms.contact')</form>`. This approach has led me to run into this error. I added enctype attribute to the wrong form because they both share the same include. Fixed it. Thanks.